# Linux. Заменить текст файла на текст из второго файла

Tags: linux, текст

Входной файл содержит произвольный текст. Во втором файле содержатся замены слов (2 колонки: 1 - что, 2 - на что меняем). Используя утилиты awk и sed произвести замены, соответствующие второму файлу в первом.

Хорошая задача, но ума не приложу как сделать, прошу помощи

Comment: **Два** раза `sed` позвать, `awk` не нужен.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что нужно задействовать 2 переменные, одна для первого файла, другая для первой колонки. И через фор их сравнивать и сразу же менять. Тогда нужен только 1 сед, разве нет? Но опять же, не знаю как это реализовать, совсем новичок в LINUX

Comment: Какой _for_?! Просто два запуска _sed_, один в другом. Всё.

Comment: Вы бы хоть пару фрагментов файлов привели.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

раз примеров не приведено, будем исходить из предположения, что «поля» во втором файле разделены символом табуляции. тогда вся конструкция может выглядеть примерно так:

```
$ sed -f <(sed -r 's/#/\\#/g;s/([^\t]+)\t(.*)/s#\1#\2#g/' файл2) файл1
```

на таких исходных данных:

```
$ cat файл1
это исходный текст
$ cat файл2
это #то
текст   пример для подражания
```

получим:

```
#то исходный пример для подражания
```

---

пояснения:

- `sed -f файл-с-командами входной-файл` — прочитать команды для программы *sed* из файла и применить их к входному файлу
- `<(программа)` — это [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) (не входит в стандарт posix, [реализовано в *ksh* и его последователях](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309594/110559))
- `sed -r 's/#/\\#/g;s/([^\t]+)\t(.*)/s#\1#\2#g/' входной-файл` — преобразует входной файл в набор команд для программы *sed*. сначала добавляет обратный слэш перед символом `#` (чтобы его можно было использовать как разделитель аргументов в команде `s`), затем два «поля», разделённые символом табуляции, подставляет как первый и второй аргументы команды `s`. на текущем `файл2` результат будет таким:

  ```
  $ sed -r 's/#/\\#/g;s/([^\t]+)\t(.*)/s#\1#\2#g/' файл2
  s#это#\#то#g
  s#текст#пример для подражания#g
  ```